# Where can I save data using ROOM?

Tags: android, database, lifecycle, android-room, android-architecture

I'm studying Android architecture components specially [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) but I'm a beginner, so I'm trying create a simple app that store a user and show me the user name on the screen (the user can be just a test in code not need UI to create).

When I insert the user on DB I got error **because I can't call it on main thread**, so where I can call it? I see some people using AsyncTask but I don't think this is the correct way or using another library like RXjava, I see some people using Live data that I don't understand how/where use live data to insert data on DB.
that is what I have:

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    usersViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UsersViewModel.class);
    usersViewModel.getUsers();
    User testUser = new User("Test");
    usersViewModel.saveUser(testUser);
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    public @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) int id;
    public String name;
    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
//Gets and Sets
}
```

UserDAO:

```
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    LiveData<List<User>> getUsers();
    @Insert
    void insert(User user);
}
```

UserViewModel:

```
public class UsersViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private LiveData<List<User>> users;
    private AppDatabase mDb;
    public UsersViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mDb = AppDatabase.getInMemoryDatabase(this.getApplication().getApplicationContext());
        users = mDb.userModel().getUsers();
    }
    LiveData<List<User>>getUsers(){
        return users;
    }
    void saveUser(User user) {
        mDb.userModel().insert(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> i see some people using asyncTask but i dont think this is the corret way or using another library like RXjava

It is correct

> where i can call it?

On a separate thread. The simplest non-Android example would be

```
// works (pre-java8)
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mAppDatabase.userDao().insert(u);
    }
};
t.start();
```

The [Android example architecture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicRxJavaSample) code is a good starting point for doing RX work.

Kotlin also provides simpler threading syntax

Comment: So the best or even the "normal way" to do this is using RXjava (correct me if i`m wrong) not a native way to do this? i see other examples [like this](https://github.com/danprado/android-architecture-components-sample) that not use use RXjava o explicit Threads, but i am very newbie so maybe i am wrong or not seeing something

Comment: in your posted link they call `.allowMainThreadQueries().build()` on the Room databaseBuilder in the [Application class](https://github.com/danprado/android-architecture-components-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/daniloprado/tasklist/AppDatabase.java)

Comment: @Icaro Not necessarily "the best", but RxJava makes multi-threaded code (or just event-based actions) much easier to work with. Almost all of Android is an event... you click a button, every character you type, any external notification, it's all actions and you can "subscribe" to as an `Observable` or `Flowable` in RxJava terms

Answer (score 1):

.There are several ways of calling code on Background thread:

Java way:

```
new Thread(()-> callDb()).start();
```

The standard "old" android is AsyncTask:

```
      new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... voids)
        {
            callDb();
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

Most modern applications would use RxJava for this:

```
Observable.fromCallable(()-> doDbStuff()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe();
```

Comment: Like a i said in the question this is using AsyncTask, i see other examples without using that, maybe they are using RXjava

Answer (score 0):

call SaveData() in main

```
private void SaveData(String name)
    {
        User testUser = new User();
        testUser.setName(name);

        new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Long[]>() {
            @Override
            protected Long[] doInBackground(Object... Long)
            {
                final Long[] l = mAppDatabase.UserDAO().saveUser(testUser);
                return l;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Long[] l)
            {
                if(l.length == 1)
                {
                    //ok saved
                }
                else
                {
                    //no not saved
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Comment: in this method you are using AsyncTask i see other example that dont need to use this like i said in the question

Comment: @Tigo2018 The question asked whether **not** to use AsyncTask